# Removing one line in file

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I trying to insert some lines to `news.php` file. This lines are inserted when I edit `list.php` file inside of `<li>`. But when I'm inserting this `updates` to `news.php` it becoming too large, so I would like to save only the last five updates from `list.php` And When the six-time updated I would like to delete the oldest one. I searched for deleting in files for specific line but it only showed me some way with files 'w' mode where I can overwrite whole text except that one line. So I tried it, but the code had too much loops and it was becoming very hard to read and understand. I'm looking for a good approach where I can delete 10th line from file when number of lines > 15. Btw. I want to leave there lines from 1 to 10 in `news.php` because they are a `html` lines for the file. From 10 to bellow the format is same so I was able to catch it with regex like `pattern = r"<a href='(.*)'>(.*)</a><br>"` if it could help... My code is bellow. The `base` var is a file catched before update(on program stars) - so I can compare it in loop and count updates in the `list.php` file.

```py
http = []
lines = []
pattern = r"<a href='(.*)'>(.*)</a><br>"

while base != None:
    sleep(2)
    try:
        with open('list.php', 'r') as f:
            webpage = f.read()
        html_soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")
        for li in html_soup.find_all('li'): # Getting updated lines from `list.php`
            a_text = li.find('a').contents[0] # And constructing a string to send it to `news.php`
            a_text = a_text.replace(u'\xa0', u'')
            a_link = (li.find('a')['href'])
            full_address = a_link + " " + a_text
            if full_address not in base:
                url, name = full_address.split(" ")
                address = f"<a href='{url}'>{name}</a><br>"
                with open('news.php', 'a') as phpfile:  # I'm writing updates(new lines in <li> to the file)
                    phpfile.write(address + "\n")
                base.append(full_address) # Save updated lines, so it wont repeat

                with open('news.php', 'r') as phpfile: # Catching <li> string with `re` and `html` content
                    phpfile.seek(0)
                    for line in phpfile:
                        if re.match(pattern, line):
                         lines.append(line)
                    else:
                        http.append(line)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        continue
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You need to make a [mre] and narrow down your question.

Comment: It is kind of hard for me to understand your question. In my understanding, you want to read a file and if that file is more than 15 lines, you would want to remove line number 10?

Comment: @Kevin Ng  sorry for the chaotic explanation. Yes that I would like to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what are all the other code for if you just want to remove the 10th line from a file. Nonetheless, I wrote these two examples of two methods for you to use. Note that these are just general examples. You have to fix them to your usage case and what system, platform, or python version you are targeting.

Files are a continues block of memory. Just think of a file as a string of text that is mutable. Its length can be increased or decreased but only from one side and that side is the end of the file.

Method 1: Thus, if you want to get rid of the 10th line. Get the position of where the 10 line is. Read everything after line 10 and save that into a string. Truncate the file to the end of the 9th line. Append whatever after the 10th after truncating the file.

```
fileName = "test.txt"
line10start = -1
line11start = -1
morethan15 = 0

f = open(fileName, "r")
for i in range(0,16):
  if ( f.readline() == "" ):
    break;
  if ( i == 8 ):
    line10start = f.tell()
  if ( i == 9 ):
    line11start = f.tell()
  if ( i == 15 ):
    morethan15 = 1
if ( morethan15 == 1 ):
  f.seek(line11start)
  contentAfter10 = f.read()
f.close()

if ( morethan15 == 1 ):
  with open(fileName, 'a') as f: 
    f.seek(line10start);
    f.truncate();
    f.write(contentAfter10)
```

Method 2: Just read the entire file into a list. If its length is larger than 15, remove the 10th index and write that back to the file. Ultimately, you don't have to use pop(), you can just assign index 9 with an empty string.

```
fileName = "test.txt"
fileContent = []

with open(fileName, 'r') as f: 
  fileContent = f.readlines()

if ( len(fileContent) > 15 ):
  fileContent.pop(9)
  with open(fileName, 'w') as f: 
    f.write("".join(fileContent))
```

test.txt content:

```
this is line 1c
this is line 2c
this is line 3c
this is line 4c
this is line 5c
this is line 6c
this is line 7c
this is line 8c
this is line 9c
this is line 10c
this is line 11c
this is line 12c
this is line 13c
this is line 14c
this is line 15c
this is line 16c
```